# How do I access a variable in HTML document form external JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, html, dom

If I have a variable in the `<script>` tags of an HTML document; lets call it `example`.

How can I access `example` in my JavaScript file?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/example.css">
 <link rel="icon" href="https://www.example.com/icon.png">
 <title>Exsample</title>
</head>
<body>
 <script>
  var example = "example"
 </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scripts loaded with `<script>` elements (`type=module` aside) all share the same JS environment.

A variable created in the global scope by one will be available in all the others.

The only other proviso is that you can't access a variable before you create it.

```html
<script>
    var example = 1;
</script>
<script>
    console.log(example);
</script>
```

There is no difference between scripts where the script is loaded via `src` and those with the script provided inline.

Comment: So I could write `var jsexample = example`? @Quentin

Comment: In the example above, imagine that the second script block is an external file and not loaded using `type="module"`. You would just access the global variable from the external file that was created in the HTML page.

Comment: @T54 — You can do anything you like with `example`, including copying its value to a new variable like that.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to access it through `window.example`. If `example` is declared in a function, you won't be able to access it. Your external script must also appear after the variable declaration (or you can use the `defer` option on the script):

```js
console.log(window.example);
```

```html
<script>var example = 'example';</script>
```

Comment: There's no need to explicitly access the `window` object.

Comment: @Quentin There is, but only in "use strict" mode.

Comment: @JamieBirch — Not even in strict mode. That bans the implicit creation of globals. It doesn't ban the reading of globals nor does it ban the explicit creation of them with `var` (or `let` or `const`).

Comment: @Quentin You're right it can be left out. I just prefer leaving it in to make global access more explicit (as it can be confusing and should be avoided where possible).

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays in 2023, using ES2022, you can access your JS variable in HTML document from an external JavaScript file as following :

```
//in your test.js file
const myVar = `John DOE`
export default {myVar}
```

then in your HTML file

```
<script type="module">
    import myVar from 'test.js';
    console.log(`myVar=` + myVar)
</script>
```

the console returns the following result:

```
▶ {myVar: 'John DOE'}
```